# Update MySQL row via php not working (but no error given)

Tags: php, mysql

I have the below code which displays information from a mysql row in a form so that the user can edit this information and then save it back to the database:

```
$companyeditsql = "SELECT * FROM Companys WHERE CompanyName = '" . $_POST['company'] . "'";
    $companysresult=mysqli_query($conn, $companyeditsql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($companysresult)
    ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post">
        Company Name: <input type="text" name="companyname" value="<?php echo $row['CompanyName']; ?>"><br>
        E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $row['Email']; ?>"><br>
        Number of Drivers: <input type="number" name="numdrivers" value="<?php echo $row['DriverCount']; ?>"><br>
        Contact Name: <input type="text" name="contactname" value="<?php echo $row['ContactName']; ?>"><br>
        Address: <input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo $row['Address']; ?>"><br>
        Phone Number: <input type="tel" name="phonenumber" value="<?php echo $row['PhoneNumber']; ?>"><br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
        Notes: <input type="text" name="notes" value="<?php echo $row['Notes']; ?>"><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="companyid" value"<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">
        <input type="submit" name="addedittedcompany" value="Save Company">
    </form>
```

This works well and displays the right information, I then have the below code which should take the edited data and save it back into the database:

```
}else if (isset($_POST['addedittedcompany'])){
    $CompanyName = $_POST['companyname'];
    $Email = $_POST['email'];
    $NumberofDrivers = $_POST['numdrivers'];
    $ContactName = $_POST['contactname'];
    $Address = $_POST['address'];
    $PhoneNumber = $_POST['phonenumber'];
    $Password = $_POST['password'];
    $Notes = $_POST['notes'];
    $companyid = $_POST['companyid'];
    $options = [
         'cost' => 11,
    ];
    $CompanyName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $CompanyName);
    $Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $Email);
    $NumberofDrivers = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $NumberofDrivers);
    $ContactName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $ContactName);
    $Address = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $Address);
    $PhoneNumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $PhoneNumber);
    $Notes = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $Notes);;
    if (!empty($Password)){
        $Password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $Password);
        $hash = password_hash($Password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
        $editcompanysql = "UPDATE Companys SET CompanyName='$CompanyName', Email='$Email', DriverCount='$NumberofDrivers', ContactName='$ContactName', Address='$Address', PhoneNumber='$PhoneNumber', Notes='$Notes', PassHash='$hash' WHERE ID = '$companyid'";
    }else{
        $editcompanysql = "UPDATE Companys SET CompanyName='$CompanyName', Email='$Email', DriverCount='$NumberofDrivers', ContactName='$ContactName', Address='$Address', PhoneNumber='$PhoneNumber', Notes='$Notes' WHERE ID = '$companyid'";
    }
    if (mysqli_query($conn,$editcompanysql)){
        echo "Company Saved";
        echo mysqli_error($conn);
    }else{
        echo "Failed to save Company";
        echo mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}
```

Once this runs the Company saved echo is fired however when I then check the database the old data is still in the database  i.e the changed info has not been saved.

No error is displayed and I can not see anything wrong with the php itself, any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Look at `$_POST['company']` and `name="companyname"`. You have no `name="company"`. It's not throwing errors because you may not be checking for them. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Its been awhile since I've used mysql_* but if I recall your variables don't need literal quotes.  Try it without the single quote.

Comment: @Fred-ii- $_POST['company'] is past to this page and adding the error reporting yeailds nothing

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it. Have you tried echoing `$editcompanysql` and `$companyid`? Maybe your `WHERE` isn't matching anything? Your form seems to have a legit ID in it, but when nothing else works, you have to try desperate measures.

Comment: Questions shouldn't be about syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed out the equals in the hidden value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="companyid" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">
```

and its working now

Answer (score 0):

First print your post array like this then try to assignment and database update

```
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($_POST);
  echo "</pre>";
```